# React Native + Firebase CLI - Accessing Data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to access the "Name" attribute of a user using the Firebase Database. I created a custom Database through the use of the Firebase CLI and it looks like this:

```
{
 "111" : {
"Email" : "example@email.com",
"Name" : "Jane Doe"
 },
  "222" : {
"Email" : "example2@email.com",
"Name" : "John Doe"
  }
}
```

In my code, I attempt to access the data based on who is logged in by making a call to

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/`)
```

inside the UserActions.js file.

and I fetch the data via the componentWillMount() inside the WelcomePage.js, but the payload comes back as null.

https://github.com/joshualavers/rockwater_appFINAL

Any ideas are welcome, as this truly has me stumped